# Wordpress: How to get pages like posts in a custom template

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to make my pages show up as posts in a custom template.

I have created a custom template and uploaded it inside my theme folder

```
<?php /* Template Name: ShowPagesAsPosts */ ?>
```

How can I query the database to get pages and display them as posts?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit further

Comment: @HowardE Ok by default i have a page that lists all my blog posts (blog index) so now I want to a duplicate of that page but instead of listing blog posts, I want to list all my pages

Comment: So does your current answer do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_pages()`. It will retrive all the pages from your website.
Here is the link that gives more information about this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/